# length arrangement with probability and cost

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Consider a set of length, each associated with a probability. i.e.

```
X={a1=(100,1/4),a2=(500,1/4),a3=(200,1/2)}
```

*Obviously, the sum of all the probabilities = 1.*

**Arrange the lengths together on a line one after the other from a starting point.**

For example: `{a2,a1,a3}` in that order from start to finish.

Define the cost of an element `a_i` as its the total length from the starting line to the end of this element multiplied by its probability.

So from the previous arrangement:

```
cost(a2) = (500)*(1/4)
cost(a1) = (500+100)*(1/4)
cost(a3) = (500+100+200)*(1/2)
```

Define the total cost as the sum of all costs. e.g. `cost(X) = cost(a2) + cost(a1) + cost(a3)`. Give an algorithm that finds an arrangement that minimizes `cost(X)`

---

My thoughts:

This looks like an greedy algorithm, since the last element in the arrangement always has the same sum multiplied by its probability, but I'm can't think of an heuristics that accomplishes this. It goes without saying that sorting by probability or length will not work.

Comment: Why does it go without saying? Do you see a trivial proof?

Comment: Consider the following examples: X={(100,0.1),(300,0.9)}, which fails if you try to sort it by length. And X={(100,0.4),(300,0.6)}, which fails if you try and sort by probability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Huffman's algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615768/reverse-huffmans-algorithm)